# Double Nested PHP and Javascript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've run into a bit of a design problem.  I have a webpage with a button.  The page is written in php.  The php outputs HTML that uses jQuery to initialize a button.  When I click that button, a jquery dialog appears.  The  contents of the dialog are created from an object in PHP. and passed from a php object, but require formatting in Javascript, which is also passed from the php object.

A simplified version of the code would look like this:

```
$obj = new Custom_Object();
echo <<<EOD
    <input type="button" id="button1">
    <script>
        $("#button1")
            .button()
            .click(function(){
                var dialog = $("<div>" + {$obj->print()} + "</div>");
                dialog.dialog();});
    </script>
EOD;
```

with $obj->print() looking something like:

```
$return = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
$return .= "<script>Some Javascript to format the 'Some HTML' paragraph</script>";
return str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $return);
```

My questions: (1) Is there some obviously better way of writing this code that just isn't occurring to me; and (2) how does the browser deal with the fact that there are two sets of \script\ tags nested inside of each other? (For some reason the code doesn't work and I am guessing that this is what is causing it, but I am not sure).

Comment: Are you sure there is a `new Object()` in PHP, I would think `new stdClass()` would be more appropriate

Comment: That is just example code.  In reality, it's a custom built object, which I am certain is correctly instantiated.

Comment: 1) You're returning the string instead of `echo` it in `$obj->print()`, 2) why not use css for formatting? 3) You need to have the printed out stuff in the quotes: `var dialog = $("<div>{$obj->print()}</div>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

You could just write your normal HTML and then *insert* the PHP values inside of it, without using a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), like so:

```
<?php $obj = new Custom_Object(); ?>
<input type="button" id="button1">
<script>
    $("#button1")
        .button()
        .click(function(){
            var dialog = $("<div>"+<?php {$obj->print()} ?>+"</div>");
            dialog.dialog();
        });
</script>
```

Answer to question 2:

The second script tag is not being nested inside of the first, it just seems like it.  The second script tag is actually being inserted in a completely different place in the DOM by jQuery after your code is interpreted.

If you think it may be getting interpreted incorrectly, you should try wrapping your JavaScript in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tags and escaping quotes properly inside of the string generated by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a lot more stability by simply "closing" your php tag and re-opening it later in the document.
So for instance, you could have:

```
<?php
$obj = new Object();
?>
<input type="button" id="button1">
<script>
    $("#button1").button().click(function(){
        var dialog = $("<div><?php $obj->print(); ?></div>");
        dialog.dialog();
    });
</script>
```

Just remember that what ever you output from $obj->print(); will need to have double-quotation marks escaped

Most modern browsers are able to work very well with more than 1  tag.

I'd also advise that you set the script type by changing your opening  tag to .